# What are the keywords that are used in Constructor() : Keyword

Tags: c#, constructor, this, radix

I started learning C#, and I saw that in inheritance we do :

```
derivedClass(): base()
```

and then I noticed in another example the use of :

```
Constructor(): this(parameter)
```

which I didn't quite understand

my question is do the keywords that are used like this

```
Constructor() : Keyword
```

have a name ? and what are some of them, and there uses?

Thank you !

Comment: They are called **Access Keywords**.

Comment: *I saw that in inheritance we do `derivedClass(): base()`* We don't actually do that, `base()` is redundant in that case, the default constructor of the base class will be called implicitly if no other constructor is invoked explicitly. If the default constructor is not accessible or doesn't exist you will get a compile time error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification refers to these as *constructor-initializers*, and lists `this` and `base` as valid. From the spec:

> 10.11.1 Constructor initializers
>
> All instance constructors (except those for class object) implicitly include an invocation of another
>   instance constructor immediately before the constructor-body. The
>   constructor to implicitly invoke is determined by the
>   constructor-initializer:
>
> • An instance constructor initializer of the
>   form `base`(*argument-listopt*) causes an instance constructor from the
>   direct base class to be invoked. ...
>
> •  An instance constructor initializer of the form
>   `this`(*argument-listopt*) causes an instance constructor from the class
>   itself to be invoked. ...

Answer (score 2):

As it described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base):

The `base` keyword is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class:1

- Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method.
- Specify which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class.

The second bullet is what you are looking for. The `derivedClass` has a constrcutor without parameters, which calls the parameterless constructor of the base class.

Regarding the `this`, that refers to the current instance of the class. So calling this `Constructor()` calls another constructor that should have defined in the class, which expects an argument.

Comment: Golly, they sure do hide a lot of good stuff on that microsoft site.